# SQLError() not returns SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

SQLError() is not returning SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND after driver upgrade from 7 to 9.

my code looks like

```
RETCODE rc = SQL_SUCCESS;
while ( rc != SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
{
    rc = SQLError(henv, hdbc, hstmt, sqlstate, &nativeerr, errmsg,
                 SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH - 1, &actualmsglen);

 }
```

And whenever I try to access an missing table, I am getting sqlstate as 42P01 and rc  as SQL_SUCCESS and it is not coming out of the loop. The same code worked fine for earlier version.

Please let me know how can I proceed further. Shall I need to handle each state separately?

Comment: `psql` is the commandline client for Postgres. So are you using Postgres?

Comment: What libraries are you using? I don't think there's a `SQLError` function in `libpq`.

Comment: We are using odbc api which will invoke postgress driver  version 9.1 and not using command line client.

Comment: I am using libadpodbc library.